# Find the fonts with the best UTF-8 coverage in my Emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, utf-8, fonts

I'd like to be able to find the fonts which will have the best coverage in (Windows) Emacs for those UTF-8 chars:

```
| 0x0000B7 | MIDDLE DOT                                  |
| 0x00229E | SQUARED PLUS                                |
| 0x00229F | SQUARED MINUS                               |
| 0x0022A0 | SQUARED TIMES                               |
| 0x0022A1 | SQUARED DOT OPERATOR                        |
| 0x002423 | OPEN BOX (wider in Consolas!)               |
| 0x002502 | BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL                 |
| 0x00250C | BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOWN AND RIGHT           |
| 0x002514 | BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND RIGHT             |
| 0x0025A0 | BLACK SQUARE                                |
| 0x0025A1 | WHITE SQUARE                                |
| 0x0025AA | BLACK SMALL SQUARE                          |
| 0x0025AB | WHITE SMALL SQUARE                          |
| 0x0025B8 | BLACK RIGHT-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE         |
| 0x0025B9 | WHITE RIGHT POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE         |
| 0x0025BA | BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER                |
| 0x0025BB | WHITE RIGHT POINTING POINTER                |
| 0x0025BC | BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE                |
| 0x0025BE | BLACK DOWN POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE          |
| 0x0025BF | WHITE DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE          |
| 0x0025CB | WHITE CIRCLE                                |
| 0x0025CC | DOTTED CIRCLE                               |
| 0x0025CF | BLACK CIRCLE                                |
| 0x0025E7 | SQUARE WITH LEFT HALF BLACK                 |
| 0x0025E8 | SQUARE WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK                |
| 0x0025E9 | SQUARE WITH UPPER LEFT DIAGONAL HALF BLACK  |
| 0x0025EA | SQUARE WITH LOWER RIGHT DIAGONAL HALF BLACK |
| 0x0025EB | WHITE SQUARE WITH VERTICAL BISECTING LINE   |
| 0x002702 | BLACK SCISSORS                              |
| 0x002704 | WHITE SCISSORS                              |
| 0x002691 | BLACK FLAG                                  |
| 0x002690 | WHITE FLAG                                  |
| 0x002709 | ENVELOPE                                    |
| 0x002717 | BALLOT X                                    |
| 0x002713 | CHECK MARK                                  |
| 0x002620 | SKULL AND CROSSBONES                        |
| 0x002197 | NORTH EAST ARROW                            |
| 0x002191 | UPWARDS ARROW                               |
| 0x002193 | DOWNWARDS ARROW                             |
| 0x0021BA | ANTICLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW             |
| 0x0021AA | RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH HOOK                  |
| 0x00260D | OPPOSITION                                  |
| 0x002729 | STRESS OUTLINED WHITE STAR                  |
| 0x002605 | BLACK STAR                                  |
| 0x002699 | GEAR                                        |
| 0x00267B | BLACK UNIVERSAL RECYCLING SYMBOL            |
```

(These are signs which could typically be used for Org-mode or Gnus marks, among others).

How can I do that without testing fonts one by one?

Is there a way, as well, to ensure that those fonts are non-proportional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one: don't tie this question to emacs; as a question about "which fonts do I have with maximum coverage", your want a utility that tells you about coverage.

With that covered: be less specific in the coverage you need. Instead of saying "I need these glyphs", look at what that means in terms of "these are the Unicode Blocks I need". Then you can use something like [babelmap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) to see which fonts you have installed with support for specific Unicode blocks by opening it, navigating to the block(s) you need, and hitting F7 to see the list of fonts you have installed that support it.